# Firebase Authentication UI

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using the standard username and password using the Firebase framework.

The Login UI was appearing but now no longer appears.

Google sign UI still presents itself and works.

It looks as follows:

[image]

It used to like like:

[image]

Code to replicate the issue is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    @IBOutlet weak var userLbl: UILabel!

    @IBAction func logout(_ sender: Any) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        do {
            try firebaseAuth.signOut()
        } catch let signoutError as NSError {
            debugPrint("Error signing out: \(signoutError)")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if user == nil {

                if let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI() {
                    authUI.delegate = self

                    let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
                        FUIGoogleAuth()
                    ]
                    authUI.providers = providers

                    let authViewController = authUI.authViewController()
                    self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
                }
            }
            else{
                self.userLbl.text = user?.displayName
            }
        })
    }
}

extension ViewController:FUIAuthDelegate{
    func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?){
        if error != nil{
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        self.userLbl.text = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName
    }
}
```

PODS are:

```
  # Pods for FBTest
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseUI'
```

The pod versions are as follows:

```
Using Bolts (1.9.0)
Using BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.2)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.40.0)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.40.0)
Using Firebase (5.18.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (5.7.0)
Using FirebaseAuth (5.4.0)
Using FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
Using FirebaseCore (5.3.1)
Using FirebaseDatabase (5.1.0)
Using FirebaseFirestore (1.0.2)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (3.7.0)
Using FirebaseStorage (3.1.0)
Using FirebaseUI (6.1.1)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.2.1)
Using GoogleAppMeasurement (5.7.0)
Using GoogleSignIn (4.4.0)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.2.0)
Using GoogleUtilities (5.3.7)
Using Protobuf (3.7.0)
Using SDWebImage (4.4.6)
Using TwitterCore (3.2.0)
Using TwitterKit (3.4.2)
Using gRPC-C++ (0.0.6)
Using gRPC-Core (1.17.0)
Using leveldb-library (1.20)
Using nanopb (0.3.901)
```

Its curious how the google authentication works but the stock standard authentication has ceased working.

Answer (score 1):

This works with the current version 5:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if user == nil {

                if let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI() {
                    authUI.delegate = self

                    let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
                        FUIEmailAuth(),
                    ]
                    authUI.providers = providers

                    let provider = authUI.providers.first as! FUIEmailAuth;
                    provider.signIn(withPresenting: self, email: nil);
                }
            }
            else{
                self.userLbl.text = user?.displayName
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: This works with latest version too, thank you. I was searching for solution for hours. I could not find this post from google, so i want to add some keywords so this post will be found easily. firebase welcome screen no email field. 
the versions in .lock that this worked for are 
- Bolts (1.9.0):
    - FBSDKLoginKit (4.44.1):
    - FBSDKCoreKit
  - Firebase/Auth (5.20.2):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (= 5.4.2)
  - Firebase/Core (5.20.2):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.8.1)
"Podfile.lock" 257L, 8462C

Answer (score -1):

This fixed it. It seems the implementation has changed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if user == nil {

                if let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI() {
                    authUI.delegate = self
                    let authViewController = authUI.authViewController()
                    self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
                }
            }
            else{
                self.userLbl.text = user?.displayName
            }
        })
    }
```

And revert to prior version:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core', '<5'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '<5'
pod 'FirebaseUI', '<5'
```

Comment: Hmm - down voted. Presumably because it's not a lasting fix. Still looking for a current version implementation.